# There is all weather description for OpenWeatherAPI?

Tags: weather

Where I can find all weather description for OpenWeatherAPI?
I am building weather app and i want to change background image based on weather description

Answer (score 0):

You can find all information regarding their API in here: [OpenWeatherAPI Guide](https://openweathermap.org/guide)